# embedding javascript variable within razor syntax

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a method that looks like this

```
function endcall_click(leadid) {
    document.location = '@Url.Action("index","dispo",new{id=leadid})/';
}
```

Of course it doesn't work because it treats "leadid" as a server side variable but I want to inject the javascript variable passed into the method.

I tried wrapping lead id in  but that didn't work.

```
function endcall_click(leadid) {
    document.location = '@Url.Action("index","dispo",new{id="<text>leadid</text>"})/';
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't inject javascript variable to a script that is evaluated at the server simply because at the moment this script executes and generates the output this variable hasn't yet come to existence. The only way to achieve this is to manipulate the resulting string:

```
function endcall_click(leadid) {
    document.location = '@Url.Action("index", "dispo")/' + leadid;
}
```

The drawback is that this assumes manipulating the routes in javascript and if you decide to change them on the server the code might break.

Comment: You are right.  Now that I think about it.  That was a pretty stupid question :)...  The funny thing is that I calculate leadid from a server variable, so I can simply use that.  It was 3 am when I posted ;).  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution (*.vbhtml):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function razorsyntax() {
    /* Double */
    @(MvcHtmlString.Create("var szam =" & mydoublevariable & ";"))
    alert(szam);

    /* String */
    var str = '@stringvariable';
    alert(str);
}
</script>
```