# Parameter in razor helper inside javascript block

Tags: javascript, asp.net, loops, razor

I have this example code:

```
artists = data.split(";");
for (var i = 0; i < artists.length; i++) {
  $("#artistsLastStep").append("<div id='" + i + "'>" + '@MyHelper.Username(artists[i])' + "</div>");
}
```

I need put  parameter to MyHelper.Username  from javascript array artists.

Error from compiler:
"The name 'artists' does not exist in the current context"

What i must to do ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [embedding javascript variable within razor syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332253/embedding-javascript-variable-within-razor-syntax)

Comment: This no helps me. They change value in generated string

Comment: You can't mix javascript and .NET code like that, because when the C# code runs, you're on the server, not the browser, and by the time the javascript runs, you're already disconnected from the server. You have to redesign, possibly using AJAX calls to hit your server from javascript.

Comment: Could you give me some suggestions ? This is something like a creator. In previously steps, I wrote data to .net session and on last step I need to get all data from session and dynamicly create div's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing too much about the problem, I'd say something like:

```
function populateUsers(artists) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "@Url.ActionLink("GetUsersDivs", "SomeControllerName")",
        dataType: "html",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({artistIds: artists})
    }).done(function(result) {
        jQuery("#artistsLastStep").html(result);
    });
}
```

This takes your array of artists, makes a single AJAX call to the server, which you'd just need a controller action to handle. The controller does the work of converting an artist ID into a name or object or whatever it is. You could then have a partial view which builds your div for a collection of artists and sends it back on the AJAX call.