# How do I redirect to a action result in a mvc view

Tags: javascript, redirect, response.redirect, asp.net-mvc-views

When coding a MVC 5 view, how do I redirect to a specific action result specifying the controller, action result and a parameter?

I am wanting to redirect to this action result in a `Dashboard` controller:

```
public ActionResult Location(long id)
{

}
```

I am wanting to do this in a javascript function if possible.

Here is my javascript code:

```
function MapMarkerClick(locationId)
{
    Response.Redirect(Url.Action("Location", "Dashboard", new { id == locationId }));
}
```

This is the error that I am getting in the browser console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ==

Comment: `new { id == locationId }` is not JavaScript.

Comment: You either want to redirect to another action in MVC : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909670/asp-net-mvc-3-redirect-to-another-action
or you want Razor to provide an URL for Javascript document.location : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332253/embedding-javascript-variable-within-razor-syntax

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 : use cshtml in javascript**

```
    function MapMarkerClick(locationId)
    {
        var url = @Url.Action("Location", "Controller", new { Id= locationId });
        $.ajax({
                url: url ,    
                success: function(){
                    alert('success');      
                }
        });
    }
```

**Solution 2 : Use ActionLink which would render itself as URLs.**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Text", "Location", "Controller", new { Id= locationId })
```

**Solution 3 : using Ajax directly**

```
$.post('Controller', function(data) {

  });
```